# In Shiny, how to see which action happen later?

Tags: r, shiny

In my app, the user can upload their file as the input data (using file upload widget). If they don't have their data, I provide some demo data (user can choose demo data by clicking actionButton).

How do I make a variable = the upload OR the demo, whichever is later? Any help is appreciated.

server.R

```
library(shiny)

DemoData = data.frame('Col.1'=c('Demo','Demo'),
                      'Col.2'=c('Data','Data'))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # option 1: use demo data
    getDemo = eventReactive(input$Demo,{
        DemoData
    })

    # option 2: user upload data
    getUpload = reactive({
        inFile = input$file
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    })

    # need getData() to be option 1 or 2, whichever happened later
    # should respond to multiple times of changing between option 1 and 2
    getData = # ??? getDemo() or getUpload(), whichever is later

    # show the data
    output$InputData = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( getData() )
    })

})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel(h2("Hello Shiny")),

    sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(

            fileInput('file', 
                      'Choose CSV File (two columns: Town and State)',
                      accept=c('text/csv',
                               'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                               '.csv')
            ),

            actionButton('Demo', 'Use Demo Data')

        ),
        mainPanel(

            tabsetPanel(            
                tabPanel(title=h4('Data'),
                         column(5, tags$h3('Input Data'), dataTableOutput('InputData'))
                )


            )

        )
    )
))
```

UserData.R (maybe make it easier for you to test)

```
getwd()
setwe()

UserData = data.frame('Col.1'=c('User','User'),
                      'Col.2'=c('Data','Data'))

write.csv(UserData, file="UserData.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use observers, one to watch the demo button and one to watch for file uploads.  Both update the same reactive data, so you see the effect of whichever happened last.

```
library(shiny)

DemoData <- data.frame('Col.1'=1:10,
    'Col.2'=rnorm(10))

shinyApp(
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
        titlePanel(h2("Hello Shiny")),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                fileInput('file', 
                          'Choose CSV File (two columns: Town and State)',
                          accept=c('text/csv',
                              'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                              '.csv')
                          ),
                actionButton('Demo', 'Use Demo Data')
            ),
            mainPanel(
                tabsetPanel(            
                    tabPanel(title=h4('Data'),
                             column(5, tags$h3('Input Data'), tableOutput('InputData'))
                             )
                )
            )
        )
    )),
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        values <- reactiveValues()  # store values to be changed by observers
        values$data <- data.frame()

        ## Observer for uploaded file
        observe({
            inFile = input$file
            if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
            values$data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
        })

        ## Observer for demo data button
        observe({
            if (input$Demo > 0)  # otherwise demo data shows on startup
                values$data <- DemoData
        })

        ## show the data
        output$InputData = renderTable({
            values$data
        })

    })
)
```

Comment: thank you @Legilzelt for your help again! <3 <3  I now understand how to use observe:) But ... now my Rstudio crashes as soon as I run the app. It shows two lines of messages:  loading shiny, and the second line occured right before crash (second line should be Listening to XXX.XXX.)... Same crashed happens when I test with the simplest sample I copied from Rstudio website...) I tried reinstalling R and Rstudio and updating all packages... Do you happen to know about this situation? Thanks Legalizelt!

Comment: Hi LegalizeIt! I get the crash problem fixed (at least for now - it's probably caused by applying toupper() to numeric). I tried your code and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi LegalizeIt, of course the crash occurred before using your code! It displays "Loading shiny, Listening to XXX.XXX" and then Rstudio disappears without anything. I fixed this by choosing "Run External" instead of the default "Run in Window" in the Run App button. (Was this a stupid mistake?...) And then after fixing this, still my code stuck there with no response. I found it was probably caused by applying toupper() to numeric (Don't know why it worked last week...). Anyways your code works perfect! My whole code works for now, hopefully it will continue to work...